# Theorem 1.43 Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions Evans & Gariepy

Tags: measure-theory

In the last section of the proof of Theorem 1.43 (Uniform integrability and weak convergence), how do we know that $\left|\int_U(f_{k_j}-f)g_idx\right|\rightarrow0$ as $j\rightarrow \infty$? We have that the $g_i$ are bounded and continuous on U, so I believe we can make them $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We also have that $f, \{f_{k_j}\}\subset L^1(U)$ and $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and bounded.

I am trying to use Theorem 1.40 (Weak convergence of measures) part (i) along with the definition of $\mu_{k_j}\equiv \int f_{k_j}dx$ and $\mu\equiv \int f dx$ to show that $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\int hf_{k_j}dx=\int h f dx$ for all $h\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Clearly, if $h$ is the indicator function of a set we are integrating over, then this holds, but I can't show why it holds in general. Thanks.

Comment: Reading same pages! Will get back to you tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're right. That limit holds if h is an indicator function. But then it also holds for measurable simple functions. Then approximate any continuous compactly supported g-i with simple functions. Hope this makes it closer to your heart!

Comment: Great. Thanks for clearing that up!